# MS Access 2016 "JOIN expression not supported" when using LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, left-join, inner-join

I'm trying to get the outstanding balance in a sales system. I did this by combining 3 tables since its a many to many relationship. According to MSDN

> "A LEFT JOIN or a RIGHT JOIN can be nested inside an INNER JOIN, but
>   an INNER JOIN cannot be nested inside a LEFT JOIN or a RIGHT JOIN"

But I get the error `"JOIN expression not supported"` when I run the query
This is my code:

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW Table1.CustomerName, Sum(Table1.TotalAmount) AS [Total Payable Amount]
, Sum(Table2.PaidAmount) AS [Total Paid Amount]
, Sum(Table1.TotalAmount - Table2.PaidAmount) AS [Total Outstanding Balance]

FROM Table2 

INNER JOIN 
(Table1 LEFT JOIN Table3 ON Table1.InvoiceNumber =Table3.InvoiceNumber) 
ON Table2.ReceiptNumber = Table3.ReceiptNumber

GROUP BY Table1.CustomerName;
```

Comment: Seems like a good reason to upgrade to a different database.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to replace the `LEFT JOIN` with an `INNER JOIN`, and modify the `ON` condition to retain non matching rows from `Table1` thus simulating a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW Table1.CustomerName, Sum(Table1.TotalAmount) AS [Total Payable Amount],
    Sum(Table2.PaidAmount) AS [Total Paid Amount]
    Sum(Table1.TotalAmount - Table2.PaidAmount) AS [Total Outstanding Balance]
FROM Table2 
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT Table1.*. Table3.ReceiptNumber
    FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table3
        ON Table1.InvoiceNumber = Table3.InvoiceNumber
    UNION
    SELECT Table1.*, NULL
    FROM Table1
    WHERE Table1.InvoiceNumber NOT IN (SELECT Table3.InvoiceNumber FROM Table3)
 )
ON Table2.ReceiptNumber = Table3.ReceiptNumber
GROUP BY Table1.CustomerName;
```

Comment: I tried the exact same code but I get error saying "Syntax error in join operation"

Answer (score 0):

I always struggle with MS Access SQL.  But with a little help from the table designer I think I have found your syntax error.  Try changing the FROM clause to:

```
FROM 
    (
        Table2 INNER JOIN Table3 ON Table2.ReceiptNumber = Table3.ReceiptNumber
    ) 
LEFT JOIN Table1 ON Table3.InvoiceNumber = Table1.InvoiceNumber;
```

The key here is to refactor your query so that the INNER joins appears within the brackets and the LEFT join appears outside.

Comment: Sorry there was a typo in my answer.  I've corrected it.

Comment: Looking back at your original query I'm not sure it makes sense.  Inner joining table3 to table2 negates the effect of outer joining table1 to table3.  You cannot have non-matching records from table3, because they must appear in Table2.  This is why the *JOIN expression not supported* error occurs.  If my example doesn't return the expected results add some sample records and expected output to your question.

Comment: I also had the feeling that the original query was non-sensical.